# How to marshal this nested, variable-length C structure in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

```
typedef struct pt_bir {
    PT_BIR_HEADER Header;
    BYTE Data[1]; //variable length based on pt_bir_header.Length
} PT_BIR

typedef struct pt_bir_header {
    DWORD Length;
    BYTE HeaderVersion;
    BYTE Type;
    WORD FormatOwner;
    WORD FormatID;
    CHAR Quality;
    BYTE Purpose;
    DWORD FactorsMask;
} PT_BIR_HEADER
```

And my C function is:

```
PT_STATUS LoadFinger (
    IN PT_CONNECTION hConnection,
    IN PT_LONG lSlotNr,
    IN PT_BOOL boReturnPayload,
    OUT PT_BIR **ppStoredTemplate
)
```

Now I need to do the wrapper for the above C function in C#.

How should I marshal the `PT_BIR**` structure and how should I unmarshal it after return of this function?

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to unmarshal this manually. First of all declare the header struct in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PT_BIR_HEADER
{
    public int Length; 
    public byte HeaderVersion; 
    public byte Type; 
    public ushort FormatOwner; 
    public ushort FormatID; 
    public char Quality; 
    public byte Purpose; 
    public uint FactorsMask; 
}
```

Then for the function declaration declare the `ppStoredTemplate` parameter like this:

```
out IntPtr ppStoredTemplate
```

Once the function returns and you have `ppStoredTemplate`, then you can unmarshal it. First of all pull out the header:

```
PT_BIR_HEADER header = (PT_BIR_HEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppStoredTemplate, 
  typeof(PT_BIR_HEADER));
```

And then you can unpack the data:

```
byte[] data = new byte[header.Length];
Marshal.Copy(ppStoredTemplate + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PT_BIR_HEADER)), data, 0, 
    header.Length);
```

Comment: Thank u very much this too worked for me... nice answer from ur side.

Comment: I have one more question but i cant post here bcz i can ask after 90 mins of the previous question.   how to get connect with u to ask a question.

Comment: No, we don't do that. Sorry. It won't be long before you can ask again.

Comment: typedef struct pt_input_bir {
    PT_BYTE byForm; 
    union {
    PT_BIR *pBIR; 
    PT_LONG lSlotNr; 
    PT_BYTE abyReserved[20]; 
    } InputBIR;
    } PT_INPUT_BIR

    typedef struct pt_bir {
    PT_BIR_HEADER Header; 
    PT_BYTE Data[1]; 
    } PT_BIR
and the C function is 
    PT_STATUS StoreFinger (
    IN PT_CONNECTION hConnection,
    IN PT_INPUT_BIR *pTemplate,
    OUT PT_LONG *plSlotNr
    )  How to marshall and unmarshal the return output pls help me.

Comment: ABOVE IS MY QUESTION.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer that in comments. I'm afraid you'll just have to wait.

Comment: Oh ok,  One thing, how to marshall a struct contain union{} and how to unmarshall the output?

Comment: There are lots and lots of examples concerning unions around. You use LayoutKind.Explicit and make all the fields have offset 0.

Comment: Hi David,  i did what u told to me I have put explicit and made all fieldset to zero eventhough i am getting the exception namley " Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field".

Comment: Why would I spend more time helping you? You edit old questions to which I already provided answers. You edit them to ask a completely different question and then unaccept the answer already provided. You'll need to find somebody else to help you. Why would I spend more time on this?

Comment: You can find what you need in my answer to your third question if you would only read it. Please do so and address any further queries on this topic there.