# How to marshal this nested, and Pointer Used C structure in C#

Tags: pinvoke

```
typedef struct pt_input_bir 
{    
PT_BYTE byForm; 

    union {
    PT_BIR *pBIR; ///< Used when byForm = PT_FULLBIR_INPUT */
    PT_LONG lSlotNr; ///< Used when byForm = PT_SLOT_INPUT */
    PT_BYTE abyReserved[20]; /** For future use */
         } InputBIR;
} PT_INPUT_BIR

typedef struct pt_bir {
PT_BIR_HEADER Header; 
PT_BYTE Data[1]; 
} PT_BIR

typedef struct pt_bir_header {
PT_DWORD Length; 
PT_BYTE HeaderVersion; 
PT_BYTE Type; 
PT_WORD FormatOwner; 
PT_WORD FormatID; 
PT_CHAR Quality; 
PT_BYTE Purpose; 
PT_DWORD FactorsMask; 
} PT_BIR_HEADER
```

and the C function is

```
PT_STATUS StoreFinger (
IN PT_CONNECTION hConnection,
IN PT_INPUT_BIR *pTemplate,
OUT PT_LONG *plSlotNr
)
```

Now I need to do the wrapper for the above C function in C#.

How should I marshal the PT_INPUT_BIR* structure and how should I unmarshal it after return of this function?

Please help me to solve this.

/********************** FOR MORE DETAIL ABOUT THIS QUESTION**************************/

1. C struct and function are defined in above. pls refer there.
2. C# Struct :

For C# struct declaration i have maintatined two struct for the one C struct. bcz one is for setting the values and another one id for passing to c function.

```
C# app struct:

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]//for app
    public struct FPINPUTBIR
    {
        public byte byForm;
        public InputBIRType InputBIR;       
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] // here when i use explicit it throws exception so i         removed it.
    public struct InputBIRType
    {
       // [FieldOffset(0)]
        public FPBIR pBIR;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        public int lSlotNr;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public byte[] abyReserved;
    }

     C# wrapper struct:

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FP_INPUTBIR
    {
        public byte byForm;
        public IntPtr mIPBIR;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 20, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct Input_BIRType
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public IntPtr mBIR;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int lSlotNr;
        //[FieldOffset(8)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        //public byte[] abyReserved;
    }
```

finally i will copy the value from the C# app struct to wrapper struct before the call the C fun()

2a) C# App Side Code is :

```
 //here mAppMemory is already known value

 FPINPUTBIR lfipdata = new FPINPUTBIR();
            FPDATA lfpdata = new FPDATA();    

                lfipdata.byForm = (byte)eFPVerifyBy.FULLBIR_INPUT;
                lfipdata.InputBIR = new InputBIRType();
                lfipdata.InputBIR.abyReserved = new byte[20];
                lfipdata.InputBIR.pBIR.Data = new        byte[mAppMemory[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Header.Length];
                Array.Copy(mAppMemory[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Data, lfipdata.InputBIR.pBIR.Data, mAppMemory[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Header.Length);
                lfipdata.InputBIR.pBIR.Header = mAppMemory[listBox2.SelectedIndex].Header;

                 Verify(ref lfipdata); //calling from C# APP side to C# wrapper
```

C# wrapper side:

```
public int Verify(ref FPINPUTBIR apStoredTemplate )
        {
           // i passed the args (apStoredTemplate ) but throws exception struct mismatch with C struct.

            //here i don't know what should i do. 

           CDLL.StoreFinger(..,ref apStoredTemplate,.. );  //pls refer the C function above
        }
```

Questions:

1. Do i really need two C# structures for this.
2. what should i do inside the  C# wrapper  function.  please remeber i have two C# struct with diff members.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a fugly mother, pt_bir is a variable length struct with no hint what "Data" might mean.  Also completely unclear whether the memory allocated for the struct needs to stay valid after the call.  Bitness matters a great deal for alignment.  Doing this in a C++/CLI wrapper is never a bad idea.

Comment: It looks pretty much like any other union, combined with what you learned in your other recent questions.

Comment: Hi David, My doubt is how to unmarshall the result output. Can u post the sample code here. that will help me to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What part are you stuck with? This looks much like your previous post.

Comment: I also agree with Hans. Using C++/CLI will be easier for you.

Comment: byte lbyData = Marshal.ReadByte(lnewtemplate);
  lTemp = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(lnewtemplate,        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)));
 Input_BIRType lunionData = (Input_BIRType)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lTemp, typeof(Input_BIRType));

Comment: Hi David, i have urgently have one question ,, kindly look my latest question and help me.

Comment: I personally don't want to answer this because we don't know enough about who owns and allocates the memory

Comment: we only allocate all memory and give to C dll. pbm is i was allocated and fllled the values to this struct but i could not pass this struct to C dll , exception is came says MEmory corrupt like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to marshal this nested, variable-length C structure in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186722/how-to-marshal-this-nested-variable-length-c-structure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I am waiting if any one answered i am very happy to finish this by tonight.

Comment: So all memory allocated on the C# side, and deallocated there too when function returns? Those details should be in the question.

Comment: My answer was sloppy. I've tried to clean it up. Even if I've still got some detail wrong, the key ideas will be found there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a little extension on what you used in the previous question for `PT_BIR`. There we marshalled that variable length struct as `byte[]`. You can use the same code to generate the byte array, and I won't revisit that.

Next you need the union. That is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 20)]
public struct PT_INPUT_BIR_UNION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr pBIR; 
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int lSlotNr; // I'm guessing what PT_LONG is
}
```

No need to declare the reserved part of the union. The size takes care of that.

Then `PT_INPUT_BIR` is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PT_INPUT_BIR
{
    Byte byForm;
    PT_INPUT_BIR_UNION InputBirUnion;
}
```

Then you need to use `GCHandle` to pin the `PT_BIR` byte array. Let's keep to the same naming as used at that question, and assume that the `PT_BIR` is held in a `byte[]` variable named `data`.

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
try
{
    PT_INPUT_BIR inputBir;
    inputBir.byForm := ...;
    inputBir.InputBirUnion.pBIR = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    // now call StoreFinger passing ref inputBir
}
finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
```

When you declare `StoreFinger` the `PT_BIR*` parameter should be declared as `ref PT_BIR`.

Comment: Hi David, This was worked for me. thanks for ur time.